# why does innerHTML append a comma

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var table = "";
var example_array = [];

function tablething() {
    index = document.getElementById("location").value;
    value = document.getElementById("input_value").value;
    addRow(index,value);
}

function addRow(index,value){
     var rowBeg = "<tr><td>";
     var rowEnd = "</td></tr>";

     value = rowBeg + value + rowEnd;
     example_array.splice(index,0,value);
     console.log(example_array);
     table.innerHTML = example_array;
     console.log(table.innerHTML);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    table = document.getElementById("example");
    example_array = new Array();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="example">
</table>

Location: <input type="text" id="location"/>
Value: <input type="text" id="input_value"/>
<button onclick="tablething()">Add</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The results in the console were

```
Array [ "<tr><td>0</td></tr>" ] dyna_row.html:21
"<tbody><tr><td>0</td></tr></tbody>" dyna_row.html:23
Array [ "<tr><td>0</td></tr>", "<tr><td>1</td></tr>" ] dyna_row.html:21
"<tbody><tr><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>1</td></tr></tbody>," dyna_row.html:23
Array [ "<tr><td>0</td></tr>", "<tr><td>1</td></tr>", "<tr><td>2</td></tr>" ] dyna_row.html:21
"<tbody><tr><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr></tbody>,," dyna_row.html:23
Array [ "<tr><td>0</td></tr>", "<tr><td>1</td></tr>", "<tr><td>2</td></tr>", "<tr><td>3</td></tr>" ] dyna_row.html:21
"<tbody><tr><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td></tr></tbody>,,,"
```

My doubt is

1. why is this code adding a comma at the end of the innerHTML each time the method addRow is called?
2. example_array.join("") seems to achieve what i am intending to do but is the toString method also not returning the same content as the join method?

Comment: because... arrays have commas when stringified? hmm...

Comment: @KevinB why are the commas at the end and not between each value.. if you look at the console output i have given you can see that the commas are appended at the end.

Comment: Not an answer, butwhy are you assigning an array to `innerHTML`?

Comment: probably due to the way the browser added the tbody, and the fact that a comma between two <tr> tags is invalid markup. The browser auto-corrected it by moving the comma to outside the tbody.

Comment: @Vache I was trying to create a method that inserts values at the desired row index of a table. And found that i was incredibly stupid to insert an array to the innerHTML of an element. But was curious to know why the commas are appended to the end of the text

Comment: You should use `table.innerHTML = example_array.join("");`. When the browser tries to stringify your array, it converts it to "..", "..." (probably by using join without parameters which got "," as standard-separator) which causes invalid html as @KevinB says and produces the output you got.

Comment: @jbrosi i didn't know that the browser auto-corrects invalid markup... Thanks so much guys.. but doesn't both join() and toString() return the same string ?

Comment: @KevinB huh... okay.. i get the point the join method uses a separator and if the separator is given as "" it would work, but if the separator is omitted it uses a comma... Thank you...

Comment: Can you bedug your `rowBeg` when you concatenate? Seems like it is coming from there; therefore debug line by line. Most likely u need to create an appropriate function to stringify your array

Comment: @Andrew thx for the comments.. :) but i debugged it already and i nothing seems to be wrong there.. i think the issue is as kevinB and jbrosi pointed out..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When an array is converted to a string, it adds commas between the values.

This will use spaces between the values instead

```
table.innerHTML = example_array.join(" ");
```